# Asp.Net MVC 6 Entity Framework - Create(id) new related key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have a controller that was scaffolded from by DB, the DB has parent and child related data. I have created all the CRUD code and want to modify the  public ActionResult Create() controller so that when there is no related data  a new related record will be created.

I thought that it would be simple, ie....

public ActionResult Create(int ID)....Where ID is the foreign key.

however I cant find any examples on this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with MVC and  EF, Microsoft has very good tutorials. Check out this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-data

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.